# Using the FSharp.Configuration type provider

Tags: f#, app-config

I'd like to the use `app.config` file of my `F#` to store versioning information.  I discovered the [FSharp.Configuration type provider](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Configuration/AppSettingsProvider.html) which seemed like it'd be simple enough.  However, I'm running in to an error I can't diagnose.

Below is a screen shot of a `version.config` file (identical to the one in the link above) and a scratch pad.

[image]

As you can see, calling `Settings` auto populates a drop-down of everything in the `<appSettings>` chunk of the config but when I try to run something,

[image]

I get an error saying that the thing I'm looking for can't be found in the `<appSettings>` section of the config file.

What's causing this error, especially considering that it clearly *is* finding it in the config file, given it's auto-populating?  What can I do to prevent this from happening again?

Comment: Do you need this to run in a compiled application or an fsx script? this happens because FSI is trying to use the config file for its own environment, hence the FSIAnyCpu.exe.config reference. You can work around it by specifying the config file inside the the Type Provider reference. You will also need to set version.config properties to copy, so it gets carried over into your compiled project.

Comment: See the last paragraph in [Fsharp.Configuration](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Configuration/AppSettingsProvider.html/)

Comment: Hmm.  Methinks I need more research on how to properly use the FSharp.Configuration type provider.  Ultimately, I'd be calling this information from inside any number of `*.fs` files in my compiled application.  Thanks for your comments.

Comment: You could use the [yaml provider](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Configuration/YamlConfigProvider.html/) which is part of FSharp.Data.Configuration as well. But in case you are going to use in a compiled application, setting the path expicitly should help. I'll put up an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have bumped into [this issue](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Configuration/issues/86).

When you run the Configuration provider in FSI it will look not for the app's config file but FSI's config file. One way to get around this is by specifying the [exe's config](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Configuration/AppSettingsProvider.html#Using-AppSettingsProvider-in-fsx-script) file explicitly. Here's an example:

```
open FSharp.Configuration
open System

type Settings = AppSettings<"app.config">

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let path = System.IO.Path.Combine [|__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ ;"bin";"release";"ConfigApplication.exe" |]
    Settings.SelectExecutableFile path
    Settings.TestBool <- false  // change a setting
    printfn "%A" Settings.Test2 // read another setting
    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

This will take the `App.config` file in the source directory, but use the `ConfigApplication.exe.config` file in the binaries directory.

If you just need to set the DB's connection string, it's actually easier, if the SQL type provider has a config setting parameter, just specify the config file there (and set it to Always copy in VS), if you add that to .gitignore you can have many different app.config files with different connection strings.

You could also use the [YAML provider](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Configuration/YamlConfigProvider.html), it has two advantages, it's not XML and it's not an erasing type provider.

Comment: Seems like using YAML wouldn't have the same difficulties as trying to use the `app.config` file so I went that direction instead.  Thanks for your help!